# What could cause "Destination array was not long enough" during List.Add in a single thread?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a List of objects that I'm adding to in nested foreach loops. the operation is synchronous (or maybe I don't understand lambdas as well as I think I do) and single-threaded and the list isn't unreasonably big. I'm at a total loss for what could be causing this exception.

```
public string PromotionSpecificationIdGuid { get; set; }
public virtual List<ElementInstance> ElementInstances { get; set; }

public void UpdateInstanceGraph(OfferingInstance parentData, OfferingInstance offeringContainer = null)
{
    ElementInstances = new List<ElementInstance>();

    parentData.ActiveServices.ForEach(
        service => service.ActiveComponents.ForEach(
            component => component.Elements.ForEach(
                element =>
                {
                    if (element.PromotionId == this.PromotionSpecificationIdGuid)
                    {
                        ElementInstances.Add(element);
                    }
                })));
}
```

Which results in:

```
System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
       at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
```

Trying to cover this with some unit tests and hammer on it, but I'm hoping someone can help me out in the mean time.

-EDIT-

Thanks to Juan and Mark I've figured out how this could happen. In my application, this operation is single threaded itself, but it uses what is essentially a singleton and is invoked via ajax. Multiple callers can start their own thread, and when those invocations are close enough together we get this behavior. I've made a console app to illustrate the concept.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace listaccessmonster
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static List<Guid> baseList = new List<Guid>();
        private static List<Guid> activeList;
        private static Random rand = new Random();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                baseList.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
            }

            var task1 = UpdateList(); //represents ajax call 1
            var task2 = UpdateList(); //represents ajax call 2

            var result = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            try
            {
                result.Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            task1 = UpdateListFixed(); //represents ajax call 1
            task2 = UpdateListFixed(); //represents ajax call 2

            result = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            try
            {
                result.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("press Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Task UpdateList()
        {
            return Task.Run(()=> {
                Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(5));
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning UpdateList");
                activeList = new List<Guid>();
                baseList.ForEach(x => {
                    activeList.Add(x);
                });
            });
        }

        private static Task UpdateListFixed()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(5));
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning UpdateListFixed");
                var tempList = new List<Guid>();
                baseList.ForEach(x => {
                    tempList.Add(x);
                });
                activeList = tempList;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The exception or a similar exception is thrown most of the time, but not every time. It's never thrown with the Fixed method.

Comment: I'd ensure once again that no multithreading is involved.

Comment: It sure looks like a threading issue.

Comment: Ensured. That's why this is so mind-blowing.

Comment: Try with a lock to ensure exclusive access to **ElementInstances**. If it still throws the exception, then it's not a threading issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The code that is manipulating the list does not use threading.

However, I think something is calling `UpdateInstanceGraph` repeatedly before the prior run has a chance to complete (and thus introducing threading). That would cause `ElementInstances` to be reset to size `0` while the prior call is still executing.

Change your code to use a local instance instead and then set the public property:

```
public void UpdateInstanceGraph(OfferingInstance parentData, OfferingInstance offeringContainer = null)
{
    var instances = new List<ElementInstance>(); 

    parentData.ActiveServices.ForEach(
        service => service.ActiveComponents.ForEach(
            component => component.Elements.ForEach(
                element =>
                {
                    if (element.PromotionId == this.PromotionSpecificationIdGuid)
                    {
                        instances.Add(element);
                    }
                })));
    ElementInstances = instances;
}
```

I would also recommend using `SelectMany` instead and casting to a `List` for direct assignment to the property:

```
public void UpdateInstanceGraph(OfferingInstance parentData, OfferingInstance offeringContainer = null)
{

    ElementInstances  = parentData.ActiveServices
        .SelectMany(s => s.ActiveComponents)
        .SelectMany(c => c.Elements)
        .Where(e => e.PromotionId == PromotionSpecificationIdGuid).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Marking as answer because it's what I went with. Mark's answer is also great.

Comment: @hSherlock: Yes, Mark is right on the dot. I went back to the source for List.cs after I read his post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think JuanR is close to right, but not exactly.  This is surely a threading issue, and it surely originates outside the code you've posted.  But it may or may not be concurrent calls to `UpdateInstanceGraph`, and if it is, they're both running the `add` method at the same time.[1]

The issue is going to be concurrent access to a single `List` object instance's methods.  We know one of the threads is trying to `add` an element to the `List` ("innermost" statement of `UpdateInstanceGraph`).  The other thread could be executing code from anywhere in the program, doing anything to the `List` instance, because you've provided a public getter for the list.

You could switch from `List` to a thread-safe implementation.  I guess there's `ArrayList` from .NET 1.0 ; but MS docs indicate that this isn't very efficient compared to newer (.NET 4.0) thread-safe classes.  Problem is, I can't seem to find a simple `List` type among the newer classes.

Another option would be to manage the concurrency everywhere that the app uses this `List` object, but that's seriously error prone.  Yet another option is to write a thread-safe wrapper around `List`, but I can't see how that would be more efficient that using `ArrayList`.

Well, anyway, I know you say you've checked and re-checked that there's no concurrency issue, but if the app itself has any concept of concurrency, than given the public getter on the property for this List, I can't see how you could really know that; and the evidence strongly suggests it isn't so.

---

[1] The reason I say both threads would have to be running `add` at the same time is, if it were an issue of the "second" invocation "resetting the size to zero", that wouldn't have this symptom.  The statement in question

```
ElementInstances = new List<ElementInstance>();
```

doesn't change a List object's size to 0; it rather creates a new List object (whose size is 0) and changes the *reference* of `ElementInstances` to this new instance.  At the moment this happens, any `add` call that has already started in the "first" invocation would complete (successfully adding the element to a list that's no longer referenced); and any `add` call that hasn't already started will start against the new object (successfully adding the element to the new list... and eventually you'll notice that the prior elements are missing, but that's a totally different symptom).

It's concurrent access to the methods of a single instance of `List` that can lead to these kinds of weird exception.

Comment: I think I may have spotted how this list is access by more than one thread. The PromotionInstance object is being pulled out of session during an ajax call. If the same user is logged in from two places or a single user initiates the call twice in rapid succession, the same instance gets pulled out and the update method could be called twice on it from two completely separate threads. I can't reproduce this issue on my environment, so I'm awaiting the results of the previous change. I think refactoring to use a thread-safe collection is the better solution in the long run.